# Regex to find partially matched special characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string, match, partial

I have some strings, and want to match the special characters(@@,$$,><,...,^) from the string,

```
a='aaa@@aa;aa$$aaa;aa><aaa;aa....aaa;aaa^aa'

match=re.findall('@@|$$|><|....|^', a)
print(match)
```

I want following o/p:

```
@@
$$
><
....
^
```

Comment: Some of the characters you want to match are regex _metacharacters_, carry special meaning, and therefore need to be escaped.  Try: `re.findall(r'@@|\$\$|<>|...|\^', a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
>>> a='aaa@@aa;aa$$aaa;aa><aaa;aa....aaa;aaa^aa'
>>> match=re.findall('@{2}|[$]{2}|><|[.]{4}|\^', a)
>>> match
['@@', '$$', '><', '....', '^']
```

**Edit:** When you enclose a special character inside brackets it loses its meaning, e.g., `[.]` will match the `.` character.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really just a typo, because you forgot to escape regex metacharacters like `$` and `^`.  But, I would suggest another approach, `re.split`:

```
a = 'aaa@@aa;aa$$aaa;aa><aaa;aa....aaa;aaa^aa'
parts = re.split(r'[^@$<>\^]+', a)[1:-1]
print(parts)
```

The idea here is to split the string on any cluster of characters *other* than the ones you want to retain.  The above script prints:

```
['@@', '$$', '><', '^']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression seems to be just fine, missing a few things:

```
import re

string = """
aaa@@aa;aa$$aaa;aa><aaa;aa....aaa;aaa^aa
aaa@&@aa;aa$&$aaa;aa<>aaa;aa...aaa;aaaaa

"""

expression = r'@@|\$\$|><|\^|\.\.\.\.'
matches = re.findall(expression, string)

print(matches)
```

#### Output

```
['@@', '$$', '><', '....', '^']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Te71ve/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/Te71ve/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---